# Swift playgrounds with UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimage, swift, xcode6, swift-playground

I am working with Xcode 6, and I'm trying to recreate the code demoed during session 401 "What's new in Xcode 6". I've added an image to Images.xcassets (called Sample) and within the playground file I'm trying to access this image, as demoed.

My code is as follows (like the demo):

```
var sample = UIImage(named: "Sample")
```

However, I can't get it to work like the demo. Am I missing something?

Comment: What does the demo do?

Comment: Is the image directly in the bundle?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

1. Open the .playground file in Finder.
2. Create a folder called Resources next to it.
3. Add any images you want to this folder.
4. In the playground press opt-cmd-1 to open the File Inspector. You should see the playground on the right. If you don't have it selected, press cmd-1 to open the Project Navigator and click on the playground file.

[image: File Inspector]

5. Under 'Resource Path' choose 'Relative To Playground'
6. Click the folder icon underneath and choose the Resources folder created earlier.

You should now have a bundle that you can use with the standard NSImage(named:"filename_without_extension"):

[image: Working nsbundle image]

Note: Because Xcode will frequently overwrite the .playground folder, I recommend using this method so the resources folder isn't getting constantly deleted and re-created.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried to follow this but I can't see the "Relative To Playground" option. I only have "Absolute Path, Relative To Group, Relative to Project, Relative To Developer Directory, Relative To Build Products, Relative To SDK".

Comment: That is the 'Location' drop down. You want the dropdown underneath that under Playground Settings called 'Resource Path'.

Comment: Why not "Inside Playground" instead of "Relative to Playground"? The first one is simpler and works for me.

Comment: I think the latest Xcode beta must have altered this as there is no longer a drop down for the Resource Path

Answer (score 113):

Look at the iOS Developer Library->[Playground Help](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/Playground_Help/Chapters/AboutPlaygrounds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015166-CH28-SW1) and search"Resource Files" and you will find the answer

1、Open the .playground

2、Show the Project navigator by selecting View > Navigators > Show Project Navigator.

3、Drag the images to the Resources

Like follow:

[image]

Comment: I upvote, but someone know why it is not working with pdf files? And easiest (maybe only since xCode 8), just drag the image file on the code, it will be add automatically and you can use UIImage directly (but don't forget the extension like me ;)

Comment: Note: Do NOT forget add the extension, otherwise you get nil.

Comment: this doesn't work for me.  my resources folder is greyed out.

Comment: Don't forget when writing your image name to not leave out .jpg or .png like shown above. I did this and was wondering why it didn't work.

Comment: **Xcode 11 beta 5** Step 4: Drag the image from the resource folder into your code and you get a working image literal.

Comment: For Xcode 12.5.1, adding "import PlaygroundSupport" was necessary for me. See this somewhat more recent SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45636060/how-to-load-an-image-into-an-xcode-9-playground#47338288

Answer (score 32):

I had some trouble with this also.

Unfortunately, Chris' answer didn't work for me. I suspect perhaps a later beta release of Xcode 6 may have removed this setting.

Here's a solution as of Xcode 6.0 beta 4 (6A267N) available 21st July 2014. I would guess that this corresponds to the "Inside playground" option previously. That is where the Resources folder is within the playground package itself.

Here's how to set this up.

Using Finder - or if you're like me and use the awesome [Path Finder](http://cocoatech.com/pathfinder/) - right select and choose **Show Package Contents** as follows:

[image]

That reveals the packages **Resources** folder:

[image]

Copying the image files into that folder will do the business:

```
let imageNames = ["back-button", "background", "bg_top"]
let images = imageNames.map { UIImage(named: $0) }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! This seems like the only way to do it now. This should be marked the right answer (until a new beta breaks this too...)

Answer (score 14):

For Xcode 9:

- Select **Resources folder**
- Right click then "**Add files to "Resources"**"
- Use it like:
  `let image = UIImage(named: "no")`

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As of Xcode 8 Beta 1, you can use Image Literals to import an image into an Xcode playground:

Start typing `image` to add an image literal:

[image: Swift Image Literal]

Select (or browse for) your image:

[image]

See your image inline:

[image: Inline]

Answer (score 3):

> However, I can't get it to work like the demo. Am I missing something?

I'm not sure where you need to put the image to refer to it using only the name, but I got the same code to work by specifying the full path to the image, like:

```
var sample = UIImage(named: "/Users/my_user_name/Desktop/Image1234.jpg")
```

Having to use the full path seems more complicated than it should be, but it works and it let me move on to more interesting problems.

Comment: I noticed that the demo has the "Resource Path" set to "Inside Playground", but even copying all of the settings that I can see in the screenshots of the demo I can not get this to work.

Comment: Thanks Celeb, your solution works. Although it would be nice to know where to put the image to refer to it by name rather than path.

Answer (score 3):

You can find out the path of resourcePath using these commands in playground:

```
var bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
var path = bundle.resourcePath
```

Default for me was:

```
/Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Agents
```

Answer (score 3):

I had difficulty getting this setup for an iOS playground, as opposed to an OS X playground. Trying to do it using bundles and relative paths makes it more complicated.

If you just want to get your hands on an image quickly, you can also just use absolute file path:

On iOS:

```
# iOS
let absoluteImagePath = "/absolute/path/to/image.png"
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: absoluteImagePath)
```

And on OS X

```
# OS X
let absoluteImagePath = "/absolute/path/to/image.png"
let image = NSImage(contentsOfFile: absoluteImagePath)
```

Comment: For some reason I'm having some trouble with this. My error reads: "Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)." Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, I'm noticing the same thing. They changed something, at least as of Xcode6-Beta6, so that with an iOS playground you can't use UIImage(contentsOfFile:) to grab an image using the absolute path. I'm not sure if this is intended behavior due to a filesystem sandbox, a bug, or something subtler.

Answer (score 2):

On the iOS playground with XCode 6 beta 5 (and probably later) you can see the image inside the bundle:

1. In the playground press Cmd+Opt+1 and click the arrow under the Resource Path (this will open Finder)
2. Put your picture to this folder
3. Access it with either

   ```
   let img = UIImage(named: "logo.png", inBundle: NSBundle.mainBundle(),
                     compatibleWithTraitCollection: nil)
   ```

   or

   ```
   let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("logo", ofType: "png")
   let img = UIImage(contentsOfFile:path)
   ```

   or in Swift 4:

   ```
   let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"logo", ofType: "png")
   let img = NSImage(contentsOfFile:path!)
   ```

Comment: this worked for me, and avoided the BAD_ACCESS I kept getting otherwise

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me on Xcode Version 6.1.1.

1. Create Playground file under same directory as main storyboard.

   [image: Folder Structure]
2. Open Utilities pane for Playground file, and click the right arrow in `Resource Path` section to add your images in that directory.

   [image: Resource Path for Playground]
3. Test image within Playground file.

   [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

Using XCode 6.3.1 and running playground in full simulator (iOS) I had to do the following:

1. Find your .playground file in finder
2. Right click it -> show package contents
3. If it doesn't already exist, create a folder named Resources inside the package
4. Add your image there

Then just instantiate with
`let i = UIImage(named: "filename.png")`

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why it is not working the easy way with PDF images.

I had to add this extension to load PDF images into my Playground:

```swift
extension UIImage {

    static func fromPDF(_ url: URL) -> UIImage? {
        var image: UIImage?
        guard
            let doc  = CGPDFDocument(url as CFURL),
            let page = doc .page(at: 1)
        else { return nil }

        let pageRect = page.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: pageRect.size)

        image = renderer.image { ctx in
            UIColor.clear.set()
            ctx.fill(pageRect)
            ctx.cgContext.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: pageRect.size.height)
            ctx.cgContext.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
            ctx.cgContext.drawPDFPage(page)
        }
        return image
    }
}

// Given the file "myImage.pdf" was added to your Playground's Resources folder.
let image = UIImage.fromPDF(#fileLiteral(resourceName: "myImage.pdf"))
```

It is based on this: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/90990

Comment: this helped me a lot, tnx