# About UIImage in Swift Playground

Tags: swift, xcode6

I created a swift playground in my project. But When I  add this

```
var img2 = UIImage(named : "Demo")
```

It gives me the following Console Output:

> Playground execution failed: error: Execution was interrupted, reason:
>   EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20). The process has been left at
>   the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return
>   to the state before expression evaluation.
>   * thread #1: tid = 0xac9f4, 0x00000001001a8797 libswift_stdlib_core.dylib`(anonymous
>   namespace)::getImplementationForType(swift::Metadata const*,
>   swift::OpaqueValue const*) + 247, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread',
>   stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)   * frame #0:
>   0x00000001001a8797 libswift_stdlib_core.dylib`(anonymous
>   namespace)::getImplementationForType(swift::Metadata const*,
>   swift::OpaqueValue const*) + 247
>       frame #1: 0x00000001001a8416 libswift_stdlib_core.dylib`swift_reflectAny + 198
>       frame #2: 0x000000010033d603 PlaygroundLogger`PlaygroundLogger.PlaygroundObjectWriter.encode_object
>   (PlaygroundLogger.PlaygroundObjectWriter)(A, Swift.String) -> () +
>   707
>       frame #3: 0x000000010031ba5f PlaygroundLogger`playground_log + 319
>       frame #4: 0x000000010bafa174

I added the image in Images.xcassets. I can run this code in my .swift file, but not in my .playground.

I try to change the Resource Path in the playground settings. Only 'None' option can run , the others give me the error message:

> "Playground execution terminated because the playground process exited
>   unexpected"

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Seems like a fine question to me.

Answer (score 3):

Under "File Inspector" go to "Playground Settings" and select "Resource Path" -> "Absolute path", and below that there is the folder icon, tap on it. it will open the "Finder", now you can select the your Resource/Images Folder and tap "Choose". you can just use the image name with our extension  like below:

```
let image = UIImage(named:"photo1")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting your Playground settings and enter the full path, where you stored the image.

```
var img2 = UIImage(named: "path/to/the/image")
```

Credits: [Swift playgrounds with UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069479/swift-playgrounds-with-uiimage)

Comment: I think it is ok now . But I must reset my playground setting , and reboot my Xcode 6 . The code can run now . Thx for your help

Comment: If everything works for, you can go on and close this issue by accepting this answer :)