# UIImage not rendering in Xcode 6.3.1 Playground

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift-playground

I spent two hours trying to make this simple code to work, with no luck.

What I did:

- I put a resource in the **Resources** directory.
- I referenced the resource as `UImage(named: "resource.jpg")`

This is not a duplicate question as the Playground settings went through a major change in 6.3.1

However, nothing is showing up. Here's a snapshot of my screen. As you can see there's no playground indicator running.

[image]

Comment: try let imagePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("img_3", ofType: "jpg")! ;


let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)

Comment: BTW your method should work and it is not even displaying "Hello, playground"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift playgrounds with UIImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069479/swift-playgrounds-with-uiimage)

Comment: I tried the suggestions above and there's nothing showing up. It is totally going awkward on me

Comment: @Arbitur it's not a duplicate. I tried the other answer before but it seems that XCode went through a major change with its playground.

Comment: Non-obvious Xcode weirdness... Any breakthroughs?

Comment: I haven't used the playground since.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem I see from your screenshot is that you don't even have the playground timeline open to see the results in the first place. The playground timeline is 1 column to the right of the playground gutter.

To view the playground timeline you use the Assistant Editor from the upper right. It is the button with the icon depicting 2 interconnected rings, or from the menu bar View > Assistant Editor > Show Assistant Editor.

[image: assistant editor button]

The second thing I figured out is that you have to put the UIImageView inside a regular UIView for the call to XCPShowView to work properly. See code below.

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let image = UIImage(named: "pd.jpg")
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
XCPShowView("view", imageView) // Console error.

let bounds = imageView.bounds
let view = UIView(frame: bounds)
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
view.addSubview(imageView)
XCPShowView("view", view) // This works!
```

Screen shot of the whole thing:
[image: playground screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

For displaying an image in Playground you have to import XCPlayground.

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground
```