# Why isn't my gif animating in Swift Playgrounds?

Tags: xcode, gif, swift-playground

I am trying to animate a gif in Swift Playgrounds. I have my code below.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "earth.gif")
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 20.0, y: 50.0, width: self.size.width - 40, height: 150.0)
self.view?.addSubview(imageView)
```

Any ideas on why this isn't working?

Thank You

Comment: Try checking this SO question and see if anything in here helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069479/swift-playgrounds-with-uiimage

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't fix it.

Comment: What problems are you running into? Does is throw errors for the last 3 lines?

Comment: The gif just shows as an image, it isn't animating. Sorry, I din't specify that

Comment: Try taking a look here https://possiblemobile.com/2015/03/prototyping-uiview-animations-swift-playground/ for some ideas on using `animateWithDuration` on a `view` in the Swift Playground

Comment: You probably need to add `import PlaygroundSupport` and `PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIImage does not support gif animation, but you can do this via 3rd party libraries or Extensions.

You can use the extension here [SwiftGif](https://github.com/bahlo/SwiftGif/blob/master/SwiftGifCommon/UIImage%2BGif.swift)

Add the linked file to the source of playground, then run your code like this:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport



let image = UIImage.gif(name: "earth.gif")
.....
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = imageView
```

However for macOS NSImage can be directly showed, you can create a mac playground and write code like this to directly see the animating gif

```
import Cocoa
import PlaygroundSupport


let image = NSImage(named: "earth.gif")
let imageView = NSImageView(image: image!)
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200.0, height: 200.0)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = imageView
```