# Adding images into swift playgrounds [iPad]

Tags: swift, swift-playground

How do I add images into Swift playground through my camera roll. In the “learn to code 3”, it allowed you to add any photo from your camera roll. I looked into a article on stack overflow, but it seems to be for the computer version. How do I add images on Swift playgrounds for iPad? I know that you will need to use UIKIT

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift playgrounds with UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069479/swift-playgrounds-with-uiimage)

Comment: @excitedmicrobe no it's not. He's asking for Swift Playgrounds on iPad

Answer (score 1):

First write this

```
let image: Image =
```

then you will see this icon over the keyboard

[image]

tap on it and then you will be able to see this view where you can select image.

[image]

Comment: Do you need to import anything?

Comment: @JohnSong you can replace Image with UIImage, then you have to import UIKit

Comment: It doesn’t seem like you can add it to the live view

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but it will break if you try to put it into a live view. Sorry. This only works on Apple's playgrounds or on playgrounds without a live view.