# Unable to get image data for SKSpriteNode in Swift Playground

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift-playground

I started a project using SpriteKit in Playground.

However, there's an error "Unable to get image data for SKSpriteNode"

code:

```swift
    func createPlayer(){  
        player.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "nurse.png")  
        player.size = blockSize!  
        player.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.5, y: self.size.height * 0.5)  
        player.zPosition = 300  
        self.addChild(player)  
    }
```

**My image name is nurse.png, it is correct**

Is there something wrong?

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: @jawadAli Unable to get image data for SKSpriteNode

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069479/swift-playgrounds-with-uiimage

Comment: Now it works! Thank you very much!