# How do we display an image in a SwiftUI playground?

Tags: image, swiftui

How do we display an image in a SwiftUI playground? I put a png file in the Resources folder called "test.png" and this is my code and it displays a blank white screen. I tried putting an xcassets file containing the image into Resources and still I get a blank white screen. What do I need to do?

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("test")
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24109505/5941807)

Comment: Joannes, thanks but that does not help. That post is out-dated and I've already tried everything relevant from that thread.

Comment: This question is really specific to SwiftUI, I don't have a problem displaying the image using UIKIt.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Image(uiImage: UIImage)`

Click the `+` sign and select `Insert image from...` or `Photos`

[after clicking `+`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUQDf.png)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHcVO.jpg)

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
            Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "imagetitle.jpg"))
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```